# Cutting rasters using polygon and obtaining pixel specific data using ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap, polygon, geotiff-tiff

I have a georeferenced polygon file that I want to use to cut several different raster files. I am looking to analyse the individual pixels within those cut areas.

One of the raster files has a spatial resolution of 1 arc-second per pixel (raster A). For each of those pixels, I want to obtain a corresponding value from the other raster files (rasters B-E). The other raster files have different spatial resolutions, mostly three arc-seconds.

The need to output as an Excel format where each row represents a pixel and where columns contain values from rasters A-E.

How can this be done using ArcMap?

Comment: What have you tried? I would try Zonal Statistics as Table: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm

Comment: So far the "Sample" tool under Spatial Analyst seems to be to correct tool to use since I need the unique values of each cell in each raster rather than statistics. Do you know how I could tackle the error messages that I described in my other post?

Answer (score 0):

You can cut or crop the raster using Clip tool in Data Management tools using ArcMap. For extracting the pixel values, you can either use "Extract values to Table" or "Zonal Statistics" tool.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem with "Extract values to Table" is that all the rasters need to have the same cell size. I tried using the "Sample" tool under "Spatial Analyst Tools" and "Extraction". I tried to use it to obtain cell values from a mosaiced raster using a polygon shapefile. However, I received several errors and I am unsure how to correct them: "Error 999999: Error executing function", "The table already exists", "The field is not nullable", "Transformation is unavailable for the current image".